# how facebook extract abstract of shared linked (articles) ?

Tags: facebook, algorithm

When sharing an article on facebook in a status, facebook generates a title, abstract and attach an image to the shared article.

For instance, putting www.stackoverflow.com in your status will geenrate

Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/
This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

(which btw: is not in the source code of stackoverflow.com page)

But when trying something like an article in news website, we get some extracted results from source code of the page (check any article in www.goal.com for example) ..

Any idea about the algorithm facebook uses for that ?

Comment: Try to log out and look at the source: `<p>This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for <b>professional and enthusiast programmers</b>. It's 100% free, no registration required.</p>` is in it.

Answer (score 1):

The meta data used by facebook to display links is always extracted from the html source code.

As @amit said, the description is present in the source and the title is taken from the title tag.
You can see that facebook is complaining though if you check that url in the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://stackoverflow.com/).
If you click the last link on the page ([See exactly what our **scraper** sees for your URL](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https://stackoverflow.com/)) you can see the response the fb **scraper** is getting.

This source can sometimes differ from what you get in your browser (though not in this case) since some websites check for the user agent string and if it's the fb **scraper** (`facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`) then a different response is returned.